# Cant get bootstrap 3 scrollspy to work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I have read over a bunch of the questions already on this topic and tried a bunch of different ways but for some reason I can't get scrollspy to work!

Most recent:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollSpy">
```

and my navbar:

```
<!-- Main Navigation -->
<nav id="myScrollSpy">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#" data-id="section1" class="scroll-link">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="section2" class="scroll-link">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="section3" class="scroll-link">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="section4" class="scroll-link">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-id="section5" class="scroll-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** I realized I closed the `<nav>` with a `</div>` by accident, fixed that nothing happened. Also tried taking out `<nav>` and using this instead `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" id="#myScrollSpy">` and that did not work either. I also thought not having an active state might be the issue so I added `ul.nav a:active { color: #fff; }` in my css but that didnt work either.

Live version [HERE](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an unique id for each section, like below. (You already have it)

```
<section id="section1">
```

Then use this id as `href` of `a` in navigaton.

```
<li><a href="#section1">Portfolio</a></li>
```

You do not specify styles for active link. So you cannot view the changes. But if you inspect the code, then you will see that `active` class has been added to `li` element of navigation.
To view the changes apply active styles something like below -

```
#myScrollSpy .nav > li.active a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I gave this a shot but still not working for me for some reason, also how would I specify what color the navigation link, I assumed it was the active

Comment: I do not see any changes to `href`. It has same value as before - `<a href="#">`

Comment: It seems that you have modified your navigation. Now you wrapped `ul` element with `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">`. So my suggestion is use `myScrollSpy` id to this `div`, instead of `nav`.

Comment: Sorry I was trying a couple different things out, I tried the way you suggested (it is updated on live site like that now) that did not work either though. I also tried the same way I have it now but with the `<nav>` and `myScrollSpy` in the nav but that still did not work

Comment: `id="#myScrollSpy"` replace it with `id="myScrollSpy"`